# Creating DDS(DXT5) from two files (RGB+Alpha). Command line tool need

Tags: image-processing

I need some command-line tool to create dds (dxt5 format) from two .png files -- one with rgb channels and one with alpha. It's because I have a waste amount of images to process -- I can't do it manually. It's no problem for me to create script for generating batch file to process all images one by one, but I need tool to create dds from two png-s.

Anyone known such command-line tool ?

Thanks.

P.S. nvDXT.exe is very good but it can't combine rgb and alpha from different files.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Photoshop, you could always use Batch Script (see [Batch Scripting Tutorial](http://designertoday.com/tutorials/photoshop/1387/batch.scripting.adobe.photoshop.tutorial.aspx) for an example) to merge the channels (with NVidea plug in installed, you could probably even do the DDS conversion too). Just a thought.